# .Net MySQL Generic CRUD Repository

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, vb.net, repository

Is it possible to create a generic CRUD repository in VB.Net for MySQL connection without depending to any third party ORM?

I mean, MySQL CRUD depends on string to identify which table(s) and field(s) you want to access, meanwhile what we have is a .Net object.

Is the only way to achieve this is to use ORM and/or Reflection class? Can't we do something about the object or string to match each other?

Let's say I got this repository interface :

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(string id);
}
```

What comes in my mind after seeing this interface is to create a personal Repository for each of my object, even though the CRUD method is very similar.

For example I have to create a repository for Employee CRUD.

```
class EmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
{
    private string _query;

    public IQueryable<Employee> GetAll(Employee entity)
    {
        _query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_msemployee";
        //Do query here, which will eventually return a list of Employee object
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Entity Framework count as a thrid party ORM?

Comment: @HighCore I'm not really sure, but in this topic I have to say yes..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is better to use an existing ORM to handle CRUD operations. You then build above this orm layer your repositories (t4 maybe or other code-generation) and your service layer.